# Optimizing my guessing algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I need to find a number (my guess) that when used in a simple calculation will produce a specific sum (target). To that end I have written a calcGuess function. It works, but I would like to reduce the number of iterations needed to calculate my guess.

My approach involves adding or subtracting a modifier to the guess for reach iteration.

- If the previous iteration's guess went above the target number, then I will divide the modifier in two and subtract it from my guess.
- If the previous iteration's guess went below the target number, then I will divide the modifier in two and add it to my guess.
- If the previous iteration didn't go above or below the target number, but brought me closer to the target number, then I will keep using the modifier without changing it.

Any suggestions to increase the efficiency of the guessing algorithm will be greatly appreciated.

```js
var _target = 40000;
var _cashflow = [1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1398];
var _guess = 0.0014534646484;
var _modifier = 0.01;


var correctGuess = calcGuess(_target, _cashflow, _guess, _modifier, false, false, false, 0);


function calcGuess(target, cashflow, guess, modifier, hasPrevGuess, prevGuessToHigh, prevGuessToLow, iterations) {
  // prevent an infinite loop
  if (++iterations > 100) {
    console.log('Kill switch');
    return;
  }
  
  // calculate a new target using the cashflow array and our guess
  var targetUsingGuess = 0;
  for (var n = 0; n < cashflow.length; n++) {
    targetUsingGuess += cashflow[n] / Math.pow(1 + guess, n);
  }
  
  // compare our new target to the original target 
  if (targetUsingGuess.toFixed(8) == target.toFixed(8)) {
    
    // the guess matched!
    console.log(iterations, ' Matched!: ', guess);
    return guess;
  }
  else {
    
    // the guess was too high
    if (targetUsingGuess > target) {
      
      // this where I modify my guess and
      // this is part which I think can be much efficient
      if (hasPrevGuess && prevGuessToLow) {
        modifier /= 2;
      }
      guess += modifier;
      
      console.log(iterations, ' Too high: ', guess);
      return calcGuess(target, cashflow, guess, modifier, true, true, false, iterations);
    }
    
    // the guess was too low
    if (targetUsingGuess < target) {

      // this where I modify my guess and
      // this is part which I think can be much efficient
      if (hasPrevGuess && prevGuessToHigh) {
        modifier /= 2;
      }
      guess -= modifier;
      
      console.log(iterations, ' Too low: ', guess);
      return calcGuess(target, cashflow, guess, modifier, true, false, true, iterations);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have the result and want to find the input to a function for which you obtain the result, the [Newton-Raphson method of finding roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) will be the best option.

Your required target `T` has to be calculated from the function `t(x) = sum of C[i] / (1 + x)^i`, where `0 <= i < n`. `C` represents your `cashflow` array, `n` represents `cashflow.length` and `x` is your guess. The function can be rewritten as follows: `t(x) = sum of C[i] * (1 + x)^(-i)`. If all `C[i]` are equal, the function can be reduced to a rational function using the sum of a geometric series, but since you have a cashflow *array*, I am going to assume that they all are different and leave `t(x)` as is.

Your problem now reduces to finding `g` (the guess) for which `t(g) = T`.

NOTE: For the given function, the obvious vertical asymptote is `x = -1`. Due to the nature of the sum, for any `T > C[0]` (the first element in the cashflow array), `g > -1`. I will use this assumption that the desired target will always be greater than the first element of the cashflow array throughout. The given method will work for `T < C[0]` too with a slight change in the initial guess, but will eventually cause a division by zero if `T` is less than or equal to the minimum of the function for odd `n`. `f(x)` is guaranteed to be monotonic for `x > -1`, but monotonicity in `x < -1` is guaranteed only for even `n`.

The working algorithm for the Newton-Raphson method of finding roots is as follows:

If `x(i)` is the `i`th guess,

```
x(i+1) = x(i) - f(x(i)) / f'(x(i))
```

Where `f'(x)` is the derivative of `f(x)`.

In our case, `f(x) = t(x) - T` since we have to find the value of `x` for which `t(x) = T => t(x) - T = 0 => f(x) = 0`.

From our definition of `f(x)`, `f'(x) = t'(x) = sum of C[i] * (-i) * (1 + x)^(-i - 1)`.

The only thing remains is to find a good initial guess. The nature of the function combined with our assumption allows us to give a very easy answer to this question. Since the function is decreasing for `x > -1`, we simply take the smallest number greater than `-1`. From your code, it looks like your error tolerance (`TOL`) is `1e-8` (the first 8 decimal digits must be the same). Therefore, the initial guess is `-1 + TOL`.

You might argue that since the function is monotonic for `x > -1`, we can choose any `x > -1` as the initial guess, but due to the discontinuous nature of the function, guesses greater than a specific value depending on the function definition will cause the next guess to be less than `-1`, and subsequent guesses will diverge to infinity instead of converging.

EDIT: After some testing, `1 - target / sum(cashflow)` makes a much much better initial guess, converging in 10-20 iterations vs. `-1 + TOL`'s convergence in ~500 iterations.

The algorithm must be terminated when the absolute difference between two guesses is less than `TOL`, but here we terminate if the absolute difference between the target and the guessed result (simply `abs(f(guess))`) is less than `TOL` since the rate of convergence for some cases may be very slow.

```js
var _target = 40000;
var _cashflow = [1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1934, 1398];
var _tolerance = 1e-8;

var correctGuess = calcGuess(_target, _cashflow, _tolerance);

console.log("Final guess:", correctGuess);

function calcGuess(target, cashflow, tolerance) {
 var f = function(x) {
     var sum = 0.0;
     for (var i = 0; i < cashflow.length; i++) {
      sum += cashflow[i] * Math.pow(1 + guess, -i);
    }
        return sum - target;
    }
    
    // Derivative of f
    var df = function(x) {
       var sum = 0.0;
       for (var i = 0; i < cashflow.length; i++) {
        sum += cashflow[i] * (-i) * Math.pow(1 + guess, -i - 1);
      }
        return sum;
    }
    
    // Initial guess
    var guess = 1 - target / cashflow.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
    
    // Newton-Raphson
    for (var iter = 0; iter < 1000; iter++) {
       guess -= f(guess) / df(guess);
        if(Math.abs(f(guess)) < tolerance) {
         // Found guess, return
            break;
        }
        console.log(iter, ":", guess);
    }
    
    console.log("Difference:", f(guess));
    return guess;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was hoping for. That a math genius would come along and help. Thank you Evil Tak. Your solution reduces the number of iterations considerably and the final guess is precise.
Now I will go read up on the Newton Raphson method :)